# Batch rename files to move sequence from end to beginning

Tags: rename, mv

I have a bunch of files that are from using IM's `convert` from a PDF to many image thumbnails. On that conversion, I have files named something-0.jpg. So, say a PDF has 45 pages, each page is:

```
something-0.jpg
...
something-45.jpg
```

I want to have these be something like

```
th0-something.jpg
...
th45-something.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for num in {0..45}; do
   mv "something-${num}.jpg" "th${num}-something.jpg"
done
```

If the number is variable, you can do something like:

```
for num in $( seq 1 ${last-10} ); do
   mv "something-${num}.jpg" "th${num}-something.jpg"
done
```

If `last` is not defined, the default of 10 will be used.  This means you can roll it into a script:

```
last="${1-10}" # $1 is the first parameter given; use a default 
               # of 10 if not provided a value
for num in $( seq 1 $last ); do
   mv "something-${num}.jpg" "th${num}-something.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Anyway to do something just like this, but for 'n' number of files?

Answer (score 3):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*)-(<->).jpg' 'th$1-$2.jpg'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).